# ExecuteScalar not returning value when there should be one

Tags: c#, oracle, executescalar

I am calling `ExecuteScalar` with a valid value, and it worked on my previous one. I'm using `using Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client;`. Yet in this call it is returning `null` when the value should be 'Q'. Here is the code:

```cs
cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("Cbrtaxfilcd_Descr", cbrEmployers.Cbrtaxfilcd_Descr));
//cmd.CommandText = "select Code from CBR_TAX_FILING_CODES where DESCR = :Cbrtaxfilcd_Descr";
cmd.CommandText = "select Code from CBR_TAX_FILING_CODES where DESCR = 'Quarterly'";

try
{
    //should be a string
    cbrEmployers.Cbrtaxfilcd_Code = Convert.ToString(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    var message = ex.Message;
    //todo
}
```

Comment: `ExecuteScalar` returns `null` where the query returns no rows. If you run the one that's not commented, where `'Quarterly'` is hardcoded, in SQL Developer or Toad, do you really get a row with `'Q'` in the first column?

Comment: Side note, if you're not doing so already, I suggest setting `cmd.BindByName = true;` so that the names are bound correctly. Without that, they're bound ordinally and you have to add them in the order they appear in the query if you have more than one parameter. That can lead to confusion.

Comment: I do get a Q when I manually run the query.

Comment: Wow. Adding cmd.BindByName = true; fixed the problem. Thank you sooooo much.